# Adding a Line with File.write

Tags: python, file

I am trying to add line while doing a file.write adding a line.  I am using

```
with open('CI.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as file:
    file.write(str('CINV'))
```

and obtaining this:

```
[['PO: CRZ229728', 'Invoice #: 2561047778']][['PO: CRZ229728', 'Invoice #: 2561047778']]
```

I want the below result

```
['PO: CRZ229728', 'Invoice #: 2561047778']
['PO: CRZ229728', 'Invoice #: 2561047778']
```

Comment: There is no way that writing the string `'CINV'` to the file can produce either the desired result or what you claim it is doing.

Answer (score -1):

I think , I figured it out.

See below:

```
with open('CI.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as file:
      file.write('\n')
      file.write(str('CINV'))
```